# Run many custom C# PowerShell cmdlet from one another custom cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2012, powershell-cmdlet

I trying to run my custom PowerShell cmdlets from another custom cmdlets. The strange thing is that I can run my custom cmdlets manually from the Windows Powershell and it works, but when I try to trigger the same custom cmdlets it fails.

[image: Powershell]

Run-Demo code:

It's basically like this the Run-Demo:
I know it missing the parameter, but 'never the less' it should find the cmdlets in PowerShell.

```
                Command cmd = new Command("Run-ContentInventory");
                Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                runSpace.Open();
                Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
                pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
                Collection<PSObject> output;
                output = pipeline.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(psObject);
                }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you post the code for "Run-Demo"?

Comment: don't you have to import it first ?

Comment: If you deploy the cmdlets from Visual-Studio it will import. But I have also tried to import(-module) the dll created manually when building the solution. Same outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of your problem is that you're creating a new runspace, which won't have your cmdlets loaded.  This is something you should avoid, because it eats up a lot of memory, and creates a lot of problems in trying to synchronize the two runspaces.

The trick is to use a Pipeline.  Declare a private field of type Pipeline, then, in your BeginProcessing, add:

```
 pipeline = Runspace.DefaultRunspace.CreateNestedPipeline();
```

Please dispose of the nested pipeline in EndProcessing.

In processrecord, your code should remain almost the same.